# Multiple function definitions with same function name

Tags: haskell

How would it be possible in Haskell, to be able to solve (without using functions instead of types):

rewrite(And True False) = False
rewrite(And (And True False) True) = False
...

I tried the following

```
data MyLogic f a = And f a  deriving Show

rewrite(And a b)
 | a == False = False
 | b == False = False
 | otherwise = True

rewrite(And (And a b) c) = ...
```

But haskell compiler complains that a might not be a bool in the first rewrite.

Comment: I don't see the connection between your question and the title of your post. Please explain or change the title.

Comment: @HansLub: I try to create a function rewrite that supports both rewrite :: Logic (Logic t1 t2) t -> Bool AND rewrite :: Logic Bool Bool -> Bool.

Comment: that is much clearer, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Multiple function definitions with the same name* is just another name for ad-hoc polymorphism, and that's what Haskell typeclasses are for.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}

data MyLogic f a = And f a  deriving Show

class Rewritable a where
   rewrite :: a -> Bool

instance Rewritable (MyLogic Bool Bool) where
  rewrite(And a b)
     | a == False = False
     | b == False = False
     | otherwise = True


instance Rewritable (MyLogic a b) => Rewritable  (MyLogic (MyLogic a b)  Bool) where
  rewrite(And x c) = rewrite $ And (rewrite x) c
```

Comment: The first instance should use `&&`, and I think this whole approach will fail the coherence check if you make it general enough. Unless maybe you're really really careful.

Comment: @dfeuer: Your proposal makes sense, but is not relevant to the problem "how do I define an ad-hoc polymorphic function `rewrite`"

Comment: My point is that if you try to make it accept `And` in the *second* argument, things will get very tricky, and maybe even impossible without the rightfully dreaded `IncoherentInstances`.

Comment: Yes, of course. I answered the question in the title, which makes sense, and considered the accompanying example (which makes a little less sense)  as just that, an example. How to generalise this example is a different, much more difficult, question.

Comment: It actually didn't turn out to be so bad. See my answer.

Comment: Neat! Maybe the example makes sense after all, though I am not totally convinced of the usefulness of promoting an ordinary algebraic datatype  
`data MyLogic  = BoolC | MylogicC Mylogic Mylogic` to the kind level. But this is the price to pay if one wants a solution "without using functions instead of types", I guess.

Comment: I guess this sort of thinking could lead toward type-driven EDSL optimization, but it sounds kind of painful.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a generalization (completion, really) of Hans Lub's approach that should work with any expression of the sort you're considering.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}
module MyLogic where

data MyLogic f a = And f a  deriving Show

class Rewritable a where
   rewrite :: a -> Bool

instance Rewritable Bool where
  rewrite = id

instance Rewritable (MyLogic Bool Bool) where
  rewrite(And a b) = a && b

instance Rewritable (MyLogic a b)
    => Rewritable  (MyLogic (MyLogic a b)  Bool) where
  rewrite(And x c) = rewrite $ And (rewrite x) c

instance Rewritable (MyLogic a b)
    => Rewritable  (MyLogic Bool (MyLogic a b)) where
  rewrite(And c x) = rewrite $ And c (rewrite x)

instance (Rewritable (MyLogic a b), Rewritable (MyLogic c d))
    => Rewritable (MyLogic (MyLogic a b) (MyLogic c d)) where
  rewrite(And x y) = rewrite $ And (rewrite x) (rewrite y)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
data MyLogic = Lit Bool
             | And MyLogic MyLogic deriving Show

rewrite :: Mylogic -> Bool
rewrite (Lit b) = b
rewrite (And a b) = rewrite a && rewrite b
```

Comment: This proposed solution doesn't seem to give you the ability to make a type: "And (And True False) True"?

Comment: No, you would need `And (And (Lit True) (Lit False)) (Lit True)`, but I know of no way to do what you're describing. Haskell is staticly typed, you see. You can't just use two kinds of types in a data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'd build it like this

```
data MyLogic a = And (MyLogic a) a  deriving Show

rewrite :: (MyLogic Bool) -> Bool
rewrite (And f False) = False
rewrite (And f True) = rewrite f
```

Comment: This proposed solution doesn't seem to give you the ability to execute "rewrite (And True True)"?